# Can we get a better Captcha image?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, private-beta, captcha

I just got my first Captcha here and it only says:

> Human?

Which is kind of boring, any suggestions for a better one?

Update:
[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52603/can-we-get-a-more-awesome-captcha-image-for-area-51 for some ideas?

Comment: We're going to come up with new graphics for the captcha/error/404 pages. Stay Tuned!

Comment: I still get the Human? http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/captcha?s=0e2bc617-ab3b-42a1-8e25-6fd783a38fbd

Comment: I'm seeing the new captcha image, as well as the new ones on 404/error pages. Can you hard refresh?

Comment: Yup see it now @Jin! Looking good!

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with the blueprint/under construction theme, I'd like to propose this NASA image:

[image: Construction Robots]
<sup>Robotic Construction Crew Rolls Up Its Sleeves - Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech.</sup>

[Usage requirement](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/imagepolicy/): "Unless otherwise noted in the caption information for an image, the credit line should be "Courtesy NASA/JPL-Caltech."

This could be used generically for all under-construction Stack Exchange sites.

Of course, once the site graduates, it should get its own Web Apps-specific artwork.

Comment: very cool image Dennis! I think we're going with a more generic "sketchy" set of 404/captcha/error images at the moment, but we're always on the lookout for good site-specific ones.

Comment: @Jeff: This one would be perfect for [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4105/lego-mindstorms-robotics) proposal.